# How to dynamically load .strings files for localisation of UIStoryboard for multi lang support

Tags: localization, internationalization, uistoryboard, nsbundle, nslocalizedstring

Hi everyone i'm working on localisation part for my app with UIStoryboard, instead of creating the .strings file inside the app through Xcode . 
I wanted to be load the .strings files from the server and use it for the uistoryboard for the localisation, i know the flow to be done using .xib by looking into this link 
http://iosapplove.com/archive/2013/01/localizable-strings-how-to-load-translations-dynamically-and-use-it-inside-your-iphone-app/
same process i followed for loading in storyboards, i created a custom bundle in the Sandbox under that custom bundle i created a folder with name of the localisation lang as per the device language i.e if device language is set to espanol then folder name will be es.lproj  inside that folder i'm saving the .string life .
when it comes to coding part

```
MainClassAppDelegate *_app = (MainClassAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

pwdTxtfld.placeholder = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"cut-iX-CM1.placeholder", nil,_app._languageBundle,nil);
```

but localising is not happening for the uitextfield placeholder, as i'm taking textfield object id and its type, when the app launches with espanol localisation the text field placeholder showing up with this text i'm passing through nslocalisedstring i.e
cut-iX-CM1.placeholder.

Some1 please help me out, where i'm going wrong., i dint enabled the storyboard for localisation , everything i'm doing it programatically.